# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused - Caused by: PDOException

Tags: php, pdo, openshift, yii2

I have the following settings in `config/db.php`:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection'
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=myURL;dbname=mydb', 
    'username' => 'mydbUsername',
    'password' => 'mydbPassword',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

That above string works in my test-machine, however in the server where I deployed the app does not work.

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What exception? Your question doesn.t point nothing. And you paste some array, not the connection setting. Please improve question, for now it doesn't make sense

Comment: Ok, I made some editions on post - check it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`host=myURL` ?? try `host=localhost`

Unless you are using a different machine for the mysql server, but I guess you are not.

Comment: My issue is when I deploy the app into a server, for some reason I cannot connect the DB in the remote-server. Thanks

Comment: Is MySQL onyour remote server configured to accept remote connections?

Comment: My mistake was that I put the URL as the host. I worked with host=server IP. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have different host name, then try chaning host name. But i think the connection is refused because, you are trying to access your mysql server with different port number.

Try with this:

```
 mysql:host=hostName;dbname=dbName;port=portNumber;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also check the php-mysql module install on your server.

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```